# Get content of div elements in JQuery/JQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have 3 .html documents.
1: products1.html
2: products2.html
3: allproducts.html

On products1.html and products2.html, I have div elements showing my products, example from product1.html:

```
<div data-role="content" id="product1items">

    <ul data-role="listview">
        <li>
        <a href="item1.html" data-ajax="false" data-transition="slide">
            <img src="images/item1.jpg">
            <h2>Item1</h2>

        </a>
        </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

On allproducts.html I would like to get/fetch the  elements from products1.html and products2.html, so this page will showing all my products.
How would I do this in JQuery/JQuery Mobile ?

Thanks in advance!

---

Im not able to post a reply to my own post as Im a new user, so therefore I have updated this post.

I now have the following (only created products1.html & allproducts.html so far). Im trying to load the content of products1.html into allproducts.html, can you tell me what Im doing wrong?

products1.html:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>  
</head>

<body>

<div data-role="page" id="productpage">

    <div data-role="content" id="product1">
        <ul data-role="listview">
        <li>
        <a href="item1.html" data-ajax="false" data-transition="slide">
            <img src="images/item1.jpg">
            </a>
        </li>
        </ul>
     </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

allproducts.html:

```
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>


</head>

<body>

    <div data-role="page" id="allproductspage">

    <div data-role="content" id="allproducts">
        </div>

<script>
$.get( "products1.html", function( data ) {
  $( ".allproducts" ).append( data );
  alert( "Load was performed." );
});
</script> 

 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Surely the HTML files are static? So why don't you just hard-code the data?

Comment: What server technology are you using? (PHP? ASPX?) This is not really a client-side jQuery question as it would be better suited to a server-side solution unless there is loads of data.

Comment: Im doing this for a project, making a mobile web site. So thats why I don't just hard code the data, to test how this works.. in 'real life' I guess you could have 100 productspages, and therefore would like the 'allproducts.html' to update dynamically.

Answer (score 3):

You can send an AJAX request to the html files and append the content of the answer to your allproducts.html .

```
    $.get( "products1.html", function( data ) {
      $( "#allproducts" ).html($( "#allproducts" ).html(  )+data );
      alert( "Load was performed." );
    });
  $.get( "products2.html", function( data ) {
      $( "#allproducts" ).html($( "#allproducts" ).html(  )+data );
      alert( "Load was performed." );
    });
```

I'll edit this answer if you need any technical details

Comment: Hi Sekai, Im (almost) a total newbie, so if you could help me in the right direction, that would be highly appreciated :)

Comment: What I did in the code part was to ask for the html content of products1.html , after I get it I take the content and I place it in allproducts.html file in a div that has a class named  allproductsContainer , the javascript code should be in your allproducts.html file